# Invalid login paramaters in parse.com

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Currently working on a login system with parse.com as the backend. I have typed up what I think is perfectly valid code, but I still get invalid login parameters.

I have no idea what is going on...

```
import UIKit
import Parse
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var userEmailAddressTextField:UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var userPasswordTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func signInButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    let userEmail = userEmailAddressTextField.text
    let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text
        if(userEmail.isEmpty || userPassword.isEmpty) {
         return
        }

        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(userEmail, password: userPassword) {
            (user:PFUser?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            var userMessage = "Welcome!"

            if(user != nil)
            {




            } else {
                userMessage = error!.localizedDescription


            }
            var myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
            myAlert.addAction(okAction)
            self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@IBAction func signInButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
let userEmail = userEmailAddressTextField.text
let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text
if userEmail.isEmpty || userPassword.isEmpty {
    println("You forgot to fill in some fields, please try again.")
}

PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(userEmail, password: userPassword) {
    (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if user != nil {
        // Do stuff after successful login.
    } else {
        var myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
        myAlert.addAction(okAction)
        self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

I believe this code should be the solution to your problem. If this does not work, make sure your Client Key and application ID are correctly entered in AppDelegate.swift.

Comment: If this worked for you, please accept this as the correct answer so it can be seen by users in the future seeking the same answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... But it doesn't seem to work... It's still invalid login parameters, and the message it shows is the message i put after else statement.  So it means it is nil.

Comment: Awesome glad I could help :)